# Can't install Firefox extension in Firefox 13.0.1

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, rdf

I'm developing a firefox extension which has been working without any problems in firefox version 12.*.

Today I updated FF to version 13.0.1 and changed the install.rdf file accordingly:

```
<em:targetApplication>
    <RDF:Description>
        <em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id>
        <em:minVersion>1.0</em:minVersion>
        <em:maxVersion>13.0.*</em:maxVersion>
    </RDF:Description>
</em:targetApplication>
```

But since then the extension won't be installed. The message "-Extension name- could not be installed because it is not compatible with Firefox 13.0.1" is displayed.
I used Netbeans' foxbeans plug-in to create the first dummy version of my extension (I used to be -and still am- a beginner in Firefox extension development), so the install.rdf and install.js files are automatically generated. Feel free to ask for more code if you think it could help.

Is there anyone else who has the same problem? Any possible explanations?

**SOLVED:**

It seems like this is a rather weird Firefox bug. I discovered that the problem was caused by an ampersand I had placed on the extension's description:

```
<em:description>Demokritos Labeling & Filtering Client's Firefox Extension</em:description>
```

If I change the above to:

```
<em:description>Demokritos Labeling and Filtering Client's Firefox Extension</em:description>
```

the extension gets installed normally.

It's a minor but rather odd bug and I should probably report it.

Comment: check out the following: http://www.askvg.com/how-to-fix-broken-firefox-extensions-and-make-them-compatible-with-new-version/

Comment: @alfasin Thanks for the tip. The thing is though that the extension I'm developing will be used by others (my co-students actually) so such a solution won't help me. It's weird because the <em:maxVersion>13.0.*</em:maxVersion> tag in the install.rdf file should get the job done.

Comment: @alfasin still nothing, thnx again

Comment: Some info about app versions you can try: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/pages/appversions/

Comment: use `<em:maxVersion>16.0a1</em:maxVersion>`

Comment: @stangelid: Do you have an `updateURL` entry in your install manifest? Did you update extension version when you changed the compatibility info?

Comment: @alfasin: Please stop guessing. Version `13.0a1` is an alpha version - it's lower than `13.0.1`. `13.0.*` as `maxVersion` is absolutely fine.

Comment: @WladimirPalant no such entry. I've already tried changing the extension version but still nothing. Something keeps making it incompatible

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an updateURL in your extension?

There is an open bug that if your updateURL is incorrect, you'll get a version error:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=740378

Comment: Problem solved (see edit), thanks for the help anyway. I didn't have an updateURL entry but I'll keep it in mind for future use.

Comment: It's an XML file, so you can also use &amp;